# ViewBag пустой в OnResultExecuted в фильтре

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

В проекте ASP.NET MVC 5 у меня есть класс, который наследован от `ActionFilterAttribute`, в нём функция

```
public override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext)
{
    string st = filterContext.Controller.ViewBag.Title; 
}
```

в `st` всегда `null`.

Мне надо извлечь `ViewBag.Title` , но не могу понять как это сделать.

`Title` устанавливается во вьюшке

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Hallow all!";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказывается что во вьюшку идёт не сам ViewBag из контроллера, а его копия, поэтому достать в фильтре его нету возможности.

Нашёл такое решение.
Использовать не `ViewBag.Title` во вьбшке, а `ViewContext.ViewBag.Title`. И потом в фильтре он будет доступен через `filterContext.Controller.ViewBag.Title`.
Так же придётся внести изменения в файл _Layout и извлекать `Title` из `ViewContext.ViewBag.Title`.

Answer (score 1):

*Кратко:*

`ViewBag` во View и `filterContext.Controller.ViewBag` - это разные объекты. И нет никакой возможности передать данные через `ViewBag` из View в `ActionFilterAttribute`

*Более развернуто:*

`ViewBag` - это обертка типа `DynamicViewDataDictionary` над `ViewData`. В методы рендеринга View, PartialView, Layout передаётся копия `ViewData`. В том что это разные объекты легко убедиться сравнив результаты вызова метода `ViewData.GetHashCode()`.

Кроме того, `ViewBag` предназначен для передачи данных от Controller'a во View, но не обратно. Иначе это бы нарушало шаблон MVC.

Comment: Ну и пусть нарушает шаблон MVC, главное что бы удобно было.